# Summing up multiple MDX queries in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

i need to SUM the results of multiple queries.

the challenge that i have is that each query has defined members (to calculate a date range)

i need to be able to combine/sum those members across multiple mdx queries

```
WITH Member [M1] AS Sum(DateRange, Measure)

SELECT [M1]

FROM [Cube]

WHERE {[x].&[y]}



WITH Member [M1] AS Sum(Different DateRange, Measure)

SELECT [M1]

FROM [Cube]

WHERE {[z].&[q]}
```

each query selects the same members based on different criteria.

the only way i can think of doing this is a UNION and than SUM([M1]) but no idea how that is possible in MDX

UPDATE - in reply to icCube question, here is why i need to have a separate WHERE clause for each query:

i need separate WHERE sections for each query because i need to aggregate the results of different slices. and my slices are defined by n number of dimensions. i emit the mdx query for each slice dynamically based on user configuration input (and construct my WHERE clause dynamically to filter by user preferences). Users are allowed to configure overlapping slices (these are the ones i need to sum up together). then I need to combine these slice row counts into a report. The way i am doing is by passing a string with MDX query to a report. but since i can't think of a way to get multiple queries into one executable string, (nor do i know how many queries there will be) this approach is no longer possible (unless there is some way to union / sum them.

The only way i could think of accomplishing this for now, is with additional *batching* step that will iterate through all queries, process them (using Adomd.net) into a *staging* table, and then i can aggregate them into a report using SQL sum(..). Biggest disadvantage to this approach being additional system to be maintained and more possibilities that the data in the report will be stale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if  this is what you're looking

```
WITH Member [M1] AS Sum(Different DateRange, ([z].&[q],Measure) ) + 
                    Sum(DateRange, ([x].&[y],Measure))

SELECT [M1]

FROM [Cube]
```

or

```
WITH Member [M1] AS Sum(Different DateRange * {[z].&[q]}, Measure ) + 
                    Sum(DateRange * {[x].&[y]}, Measure)

SELECT [M1]

FROM [Cube]
```

I don't know any way adding the result of two selects in MDX...

Comment: thanks, but i need to have different WHERE sections for each query

Comment: ok - can you explain why? - if you find a solution let us know.

Comment: sure, i updated my question with an explanation and my current best guess on how to solve it. Hope it makes sense..

Comment: Txs, Not sure I understand everything, but using a calculated members allows adding tuples with different dimensionalities, a concrete example of view one of the proposed solution is not working will help :-)

Comment: actually, i put your ideas to the test, and it is totally possible to combine different WHERE filters this way! thanks icCube!! :)))

Comment: hey icCube, thanks again! i've been using this approach successfully and it is working out great. You really saved me here :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `Aggregate()` not Sum.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the UNION behavior in MDX using SubCubes on this way:

```
Select
{...} On Columns,
{...} On Rows
From (
     Select 
            {
              {Dimension1.Level.Members * Dimension2.&[1] * Dimension3.&[2]},
              {Dimension1.&[X] * Dimension2.Members * Dimension3.&[5]}  
            } On Columns
     From [Cube]
     )
```